# Java transformer w3c.dom.document to inputstream

Tags: java, dom, xpath, inputstream, transformer-model

My scenario is this:

I have a HTML which I loaded into a w3c.dom.Document, after loading it as a doc, I parsed through its nodes and made a few changes in their values, but now I need to transform this document into a String, or preferably into a InputStream directly.

And I managed to do so, however, to the ends I need this HTML it must keep some properties of the initial file, for instance (and this is the one thing I'm struggling a lot trying to solve), all tags must be closed.

Say, I have a link tag on the header, `<link .... />` I NEED the dash (/) at the end. However after the transformer transform my doc into a outputStream (which then I proceed to send to an inputStream) all the '/' before the > disappear. All my tags, which ended in `/>` are changed into simple `>`.

The reason I need this structure is that one of the libraries I'm using (and I'm afraid I can't go looking for another one, specially not at this point) require all tags to be closed, if not it throws exceptions everywhere and my program crashes....

Does anyone have any good ideas or solutions for me? This is my first contact with the Transform class, so I might be missing something that could help me.

Thank you all so very much,

Warm regards

Some bit of the code to explain the scenario a little bit

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.parse(his); // his = the HTML inputStream

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//*[@id='pessoaNome']";
org.w3c.dom.Element pessoaNome = null;

try 
{
    pessoaNome = (org.w3c.dom.Element) (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

pessoaNome.setTextContext("The new values for the node");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "HTML");
transformer.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()); // At this point outputStream is already all messed up, not just the '/'. but this is the only thing causing me problems
```

as @Lee pointed out, I changed it to use Jsoup. Code got a lot cleaner, just had to set up the outputSettings for it to work like a charm. Code below

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(HTML), "UTF-8");

org.jsoup.nodes.Element pessoaNome = doc.getElementById("pessoaNome");

pessoaNome.html("My new html in here");

OutputSettings oSettings = new OutputSettings();
oSettings.syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
doc.outputSettings(oSettings);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.outerHtml().getBytes());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) which cleans HTML.  There is also [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) which is newer as supposedly does the same things only better.

Comment: Jsoup looked really promising, except it too removed the dash at the end of my link tag... (fixed typos)

Comment: What is this other library you are using further in the process?  I have at the back of my mind that strictly not all HTML elements can be closed - I think <br> is one.

Comment: <br> is one that can be closed, like <br />, iirc. I agree that I have never seen a closing to a link tag, this is a first to me. I am using iTextPDF, trying to parse an html into my PDF, but it requires that all the tags are closed in order to not throw exceptions.

Comment: I guess I could specifically edit the Jsoup document html and add the closing dashes, but this solution seems wrong to me, and I would like to avoid it, since I might have to deal with this problems a couple more times.

Comment: Try jTidy first that might do things differently.  The fact is that when you are pulling HTML off the web it really is the wild west out there.

Comment: I am in fact not pulling it from the web. I wrote it myself as this will be the model for my PDF reports, my idea is to get the HTML, throw the report data in it using this method, in order to save me the trouble to write the PDF with the standard iTextPDF methods, which are really messy. So, I created the layout html and am trying to output data in it. Will look up to jTidy. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Solved it! Had to change the outputSettings of the document.

Comment: OutputSettings oSettings = new OutputSettings();
oSettings.syntax(OutpuSettings.Syntax.xml); doc.outputSettings(oSettings);

Comment: the outerHtml() method on the document doesn't change the structure of the file.